# Removing unused citations from the references list

Tags: bibliographies

I am using the Springer Journal Template and I am adding references manually like this:

```
% BibTeX users please use one of
%\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
%\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences
%\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics

% Non-BibTeX users please use
\begin{thebibliography}{}   
\bibitem{RefA}
Jones, B., Plassmann, P.: imaging of skin Structure of human skin, IEEE Engineering in medicine and biology, 17, 41-48 (2002) https://doi.org/10.1109/IEMBS.2011.6091819
%
\bibitem{RefB}
Khan, M., Ingleby, M., Ward, R.: Classifying Pretended and Evoked Facial Expressions of Positive and Negative Affective States using Infrared Measurement of Skin Temperature, ACM Transactions on Autonomous and Adaptive Systems, 1, 91-113 (2006). https://doi.org/10.1145
%
\bibitem{RefD}
Hermosilla, G., Verdugo, J., Farias, G. et al.: Face Recognition and Drunk Classification Using Infrared Face Images, Journal of Sensors, 2018, 1-8 (2018). https://doi.org/10.1155/2018/5813514
%
\bibitem{RefE}
Koukiou, G., Anasassopoulos, V.: Face locations suitable drunk persons identification, 2013 International Workshop on Biometrics and Forensics, 2-5 (2013). https://doi.org/10.1109/IWBF.2013.6547311
%
\bibitem{RefF}
Li, H., Ota, K., Dong, M.: Learning IoT in Edge: Deep Learning for the Internet of Things with Edge Computing, IEEE Network, 96-101 (2018). https://doi.org/10.1109/IWBF.2013.6547311
%
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

Although, I ended up scrapping much of my text and I have over 100 citations. Even though I deleted the text where the references were being cited, they still remain in the references. I'd like to know if there is an easy way to remove them from the unused references from the reference list

Comment: When you use the `thebibliography` environment to create a formatted bibliography, you are in charge of *everything* -- including which entries to include in the first place.

Comment: So, I should move them to a file then?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understadn what you mean by "them".. The `\bibitem` chunks? If so, you  could just comment out the ones you don't need for the document at hand.

Comment: this is why most people use bibtex or biblatex to generate the list. If you do it by hand then it is implemented more or less identically to a `description` list. LaTeX itself can not help with the text you must  just edit it as you would `description` or `itemize`